# Как сделать и обработать ссылку формата t.me/mybot?start=KEY в aiogram python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Как сделать и обработать ссылку формата t.me/mybot?start=KEY в aiogram python?
mybot - название бота, KEY - ключ, который и нужно обработать(записать в переменную).
Пояснение:

- Бот генерирует такую ссылку и 1 человек пересылает ее 2 человеку.
- 2 человек переходит по ней и его перебрасывает в телеграм бота, он нажимает кнопку Старт в боте и у него происходит какое-то событие(например, пишется ключ который был в ссылке).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто, в обработчике Вашей /start команды нужно отлавливать получение аргументов.

```py
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message

@dp.message_handler(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    args = message.get_args()

    if args:
        key = args[1]
        print(key)

        # Do something...

    ...
```